# Add a line break when emailing \r\n PHP mail()

Tags: php, sendmail, line-breaks

```
$order="";
$order .= "<strong>Sent:</strong> ";
$order .= date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$order .= "\r\n";
$order .= "\r\n";
$order .= $message;
```

My code works, however, I'm trying to add a line break between the date function and the $message. I've tried it with just \n, but nothing seems to work. Is there a different way? I echo out `$order` and there are no line breaks between the `date` and `$message`.

I also tried

`$order .= '<br />';` but that did not work either. Any help?

FULL CODE:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['order'])){
$message = $_POST['order'];
}
$order="";
$order .= "<strong>Sent:</strong> ";
$order .= date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$order .= "\r\n";
$order .= "\r\n";
$order .= $message;

//print_r($_POST);
echo $order;
include "imagehover.php";

    $email_to = "email1@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "Subject Line";
    $email_from = "email2@gmail.com";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <email@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($email_to, $email_subject, $order, $headers);  
session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Are you sending a text email or HTML email? There are some differences between the representation of newlines in either format, but without the code that actually sends the email we can only guess.

Comment: You would have to send the correct headers. And your Browser would have to interpret them as HTML. Not all Browsers will.

Comment: Well, he does show HTML inside his contents. So I would guess he's attempting to send an HTML mail. In that case, I would have guessed adding <br /> should have worked just fine. Unless of course the entire HTML presentation doesn't work in the first place.

Comment: Show....full...code. I'm a terrible shot at night golf.

Comment: Ok, sorry guys. Edited with full code...

Comment: This line `'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" ....` is incomplete. It's breaking your headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is incomplete/broken:

```
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Replace with this whole block:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <email@gmail.com>" . "\r\n" .
                "Reply-To: $email_from" . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

And:

Change it to:

```
$order="";
$order .= "<strong>Sent:</strong> ";
$order .= date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$order .= "<br>";
$order .= "<br>";
$order .= $message;
```

Comment: Hey @Fred -ii- This works, but there is still no space between the date/timestamp, and the $message. Also, the From: displays the email that it was sent from, not <email@gmail.com>... Any words of wisdom?

Comment: I'd like to have the FROM: be the $email_from as well.

Comment: You can just change `$headers .= "From: <email@gmail.com>" . "\r\n" .` to `$headers .= "From: $email_from" . "\r\n" .`

Comment: I changed it to that, and the email is still being sent by the actual email address it's sent from. Not the defined address in here.

Comment: that's what I wrote in my comment above @user3150191 did you not see it? *"I'd like to have the FROM: be the $email_from as well"* `$headers .= "From: $email_from" . "\r\n" .`

Comment: I changed it to: `$headers .= "From: $email_from" . "\r\n" .
            "Reply-To: $email_from" . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` 

But the email that is sent doesn't say the sender is $email_from.

Comment: Ok, you asked me earlier you wanted the `From:` to be coming from `$email_from`, right? @user3150191

Comment: Here's what you have `$email_from = "email2@gmail.com";`

Comment: I'm sorry for sounding impatient, but I have a MUCH bigger problem to deal with right now. @user3150191 you'll need to figure it out. I have to go.